# Get data structure from model in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to develop an architecture, as generic as possible. 
I want my Django REST Framework app to send an empty data structure to a JS code, in order to create objects without the need to know the data structure of each model in the JS code

For example, I have this model created :

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="***")
```

I need to find a way to send a JSON containing type of all fields of the model (with their properties), like

```
{
    "name": {
        "type": "CharField",
        "max_length": 60
    },
    "done": "BooleanField",
    "url": {
        "type": "CharField",
        "max_length": 60,
        "default" = "***"
    }
}
```

Is there any kind of package I can add in order to achieve this ? Is there a built-in solution with Django REST Framework ? Is this even possible ?

Comment: I'm still using DRF 2.4.4, but I wrote an interface parser to automate some of the client-side initialization that must occur after receiving a response back from DRF ( such as converting `DateTimeField` to a js `Date`, creating a pre/post request framework to manipulate an object before sending/ after receiving.)  The code that it generates is specifically for AngularJS. Anyways, it is not ready for primetime and it is a bit ragged, but that code may give you a start about how to crawl through the serializers to the info you want.

Comment: Put [this code](https://gist.github.com/RossRogers/22cef9abc7346ecbfe33) in `<app>/management/commands/rest_framework_2_js.py` and then run it with `python manage.py rest_framework_2_js dest.js app_name.js` e.g.  `python manage.py rest_framework_2_js app/scripts/gen/qc_srvr.js qc_srvr`

Comment: I hook into `grunt` to auto generate the files when `models.py` or `serializers.py` or `urls.py` change.

Comment: After a few modifications, I manage to make it work. Thank you so much :D. I don't understand why you commented l. 292 ?

Comment: I believe it caused problems for me with regard to field existence testing.  The old `typeof(foo.bar)` being `undefined` vs `null`.  To restate, that code is a bit of a jalopy :-D  Glad you found it useful.  I want to productize it some day, because I feel that mechanism is currently lacking in the DRF ecosystem, but it needs a whole rewrite now that I understand js and promises a little better.